# Test dependencies of Java web app library

Tags: java, web-applications

I am coding a java web app.

When I started, every time I needed to use an external package, I would download the `jar`s manually and download all dependencies of each `jar` manually and place them in the `libraries` folder (in Netbeans).

As time went on, I started using a dependency manager (Ant).

Now, I would like to use my dependency manager for all of my external libraries.

If, after executing this change I run my application and it successfully deploys (no `ClassNotFoundException`s and no `NoClassDefFoundError`s), is it safe to assume that I have not missed anything and that my application will run smoothly as far as the external packages go?

Or, do I need to individually test out each functionality in my web app to confirm that the changes I made to the libraries didn't change how the application runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually depends on the code inside these libraries. Only part of classes are loaded at startup, thus you can miss something. Also there might be a possibility that you're loading some classes in runtime manually, i.e. `Class.forName(String)` and this code has not been triggered at startup. Thus, I would say you can't be 100% sure.

Generally in Java here are 3 build approaches:

1. Imperative - you're saying "How to assembly your code". The typical example of this is [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/).
2. Declarative - you're saying "Which code you want to assembly". The typical example of this is [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/)
3. Mixed - which takes benefits of previous systems. This is [Gradle](https://gradle.org/).

How it helps!